# Trigger function to delete certain rows from the same table

Tags: sql, function, postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

I'm trying to create a Trigger/Function in Postgres that will check, upon an insert to a table, whether or not there is already another post by a different member with the same content. **If there is a post, this function will not insert the new one** and leave the table unchanged. Otherwise, it will be added.

So far, the trigger and function look like:

Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER isPostUnique 
AFTER INSERT ON posts 
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE deletePost();
```

Function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION deletePost() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $isPostUnique$
BEGIN
IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM posts p1, posts p2 
   WHERE (p1.userID <> p2.userID) 
   AND (p1.content LIKE p2.content)))
  THEN
    DELETE FROM NEW WHERE (posts.postID = NEW.postID);
  RETURN NEW;
END IF;
END;
$isPostUnique$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Adding the function and trigger works without any errors, but when I try to run the following query to test it: `INSERT INTO posts VALUES (7, 3, 'test redundant post', 10, 1);` I get this error

```
ERROR:  relation "new" does not exist
LINE 1: DELETE FROM NEW WHERE (posts.postID = NEW.postID)
                    ^
QUERY:  DELETE FROM NEW WHERE (posts.postID = NEW.postID)
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function dp() line 7 at SQL statement
```

I am aware that you can't use 'NEW' in `FOR EACH ROW` inserts, but I have no other idea of how to accomplish this.

Comment: `new` can **only** be used in a row level (`for each row`) trigger. What exactly do you expect `delete from new` to do? `new` is a single row (aka "record") not a table where you can delete from.

Comment: I'm really new to Postgres and just going off of what I can from the documents, so I'm sure a lot of it just doesn't make sense. What I am trying to accomplish is find the new insert that has the same content as another, and delete the one that was just inserted.

Comment: To prevent an insert, simply return `NULL` from the trigger. [Quote from the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html): "*Row-level triggers fired BEFORE can return null to signal the trigger manager to skip the rest of the operation for this row (i.e., subsequent triggers are not fired, and the INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE does not occur for this row*"

Comment: Ok I replaced the `AFTER INSERT ON` from the trigger with `BEFORE INSERT...` and took out the `THEN DELETE FROM...RETURN NEW` and replaced what was inside the `THEN` with `RETURN NULL`.
However, now I can't add anything to the table.

Comment: Is there anyway I can write an IF statement similar to

    `IF ((NEW.content LIKE posts.content) 
     AND (NEW.userID <> posts.userID))`

without getting the `missing FROM` error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Updated answer for updated question

Of course you can use `NEW` in `FOR EACH ROW` trigger function. You just can't direct a `DELETE` statement at it. It's a row type ([data type `HeapTuple` to be precise](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/trigger-definition.html)), not a table.

To *abort* the `INSERT` **silently** (no exception raised) if the same content is already there ...

```
CREATE FUNCTION deletePost()
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$func$
BEGIN

IF EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   posts p
   WHERE  p.content = NEW.content
   -- AND p.userID <> NEW.userID  -- I doubt you need this, too?
   ) THEN

    RETURN NULL;  -- cancel INSERT
ELSE
    RETURN NEW;   -- go ahead
END IF;

END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Of course this only works for a trigger ...

```
...
BEFORE INSERT ON posts
...
```

#### Unique index

A [`UNIQUE` constraint](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-UNIQUE-CONSTRAINTS) or a unique index (almost the same effect) might be a superior solution:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX posts_content_uni_idx (content);
```

Would **raise an exception** at the attempt to insert a duplicate value. No trigger necessary.
It also provides the very well needed index to speed up things.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, I have it working but backwards.

It is deleting the original post, not the new one. I have the function returning 'NEW', as I can't figure out how to return the 'posts' table without an error.

Any ideas? Here is what my function looks like now
    `CREATE FUNCTION deletePost() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $isPostUnique$
BEGIN
DELETE FROM posts p
  WHERE p.userID <> NEW.userID
  AND p.content LIKE NEW.content;
RETURN NEW;
END;
$isPostUnique$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;`

Comment: @Zach: Your question just doesn't give the complete picture. That sucks when trying to answer ...

Comment: sorry it doesn't seem clear. What I'm trying to accomplish is a trigger and function that will not update the 'posts' table with the new post if it matches another user's post. Let's say userID 0 made a post 'hello!' and userID 2 tries to make a post 'hello!'. I want the function to realize that userID 0 already made that post and thus not allow userID 2's post to be added to the table.

Comment: @Zach: Updated the answer accordingly.